# Prisma migrate dev: Run command while connected to DB?

Tags: postgresql, prisma, prisma2

Context: Our staging and production postgres databases are in a managed SQL service.

Is it recommended to create a local postgres database to run the command the `npx prisma migrate dev`?

Once the migration files are generated (as a result of running this command), we should then be able to run the `npx prisma migrate deploy` command on staging and prod environments.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. You should only be using `npx prisma migrate dev` in a local/development database. Once you are done with development and migrations have been created, you apply them to your staging/production database using `npx prisma migrate deploy`.

I would recommend checking out these two articles from the Prisma docs:

[Prisma Migrate: Concept Guide](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-migrate#development-environments)

[Deploying database changes with Prisma Migrate](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/deployment/deploy-database-changes-with-prisma-migrate)